# How create symbol link for subdomain in IIS, which will open another domain running on IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I created a new site on IIS, for example **mysite.com**. Site is running, it is opened in browser, all good.

But I need create subdomain **1.mysite.com**, which will open **mysite.com**. I don't mean a redirect. I mean open in browser **1.mysite.com** and will be opening **mysite.com**

How can I do this on IIS?

Comment: If you already know how to set up `mysite.com`, simply do the same for `1.mysite.com`. An IIS site can have multiple bindings, so you just need to repeat the same steps.

Answer (score 1):

Since you basically want two different names for your website

- create a DNS entry for 1.mysite.com to point to mysite.com host entry
- in IIS ,you can just add another binding with hostname 1.mysite.com

[image: add multiple hostname bindings]